# WPF validations on disabled controls

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I am working on a WPF project with mvvm pattern.
I am using IDataError info and Validation templates for displaying validations.
I would not like show validations on some controls when they are disabled. I cant think of a good solution how I can do that. Can somebody suggest a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `IsEnabled` property to a property in your viewmodel. Then in your IDataErrorInfo handler, if the backing property is false, don't validate.

```
//xaml
<TextBox IsEnabled={Binding ValidateTheTextBox} Text={Binding MyText}/>

//backing property
public bool ValidateTheTextBox { get; set;}

//IDataErrorInfo switch
case "MyText":
     if(ValidateTheTextBox) 
     {
         //Validates when true
     }
```